# event in derived class

Tags: c#, wpf

I have declared an event in my UserControl class Main:

```
public static readonly RoutedEvent CloseEvent = EventManager.RegisterRoutedEvent(
    "CloseClick", RoutingStrategy.Bubble, typeof(RoutedEventHandler), typeof(Main));
public event RoutedEventHandler CloseClick
{
    add { AddHandler(CloseEvent, value); }
    remove { RemoveHandler(CloseEvent, value); }
}
```

This code should be valid since I've used in other classes. The problem is when Im trying to listen to the event in another class.

```
UserControl content;
if (value == "main")
{
    content = new Main();
    content.CloseClick += new RoutedEventHandler(closeClick);
} else {
    ...
    ...
}
MasterPage.addContent(content);
```

I want "content" to be of any type derived from UserControl.
If I declare "content" as type "Main" the event is found but If its declared as the BaseClass "UserControl" everything but the event works. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thats how it should work right. I mean `Main` is the correct type for the source of that event and not `UserControl` (which can be anything).

If you want an event that is raised for any userControl then create a [Attached Routed Events](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb613550.aspx). They can be raised from any DependencyObject (i.e.  `Main` or base `UserControl` or both).

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if i have understood well your question. I think that you are casting a derived class to its base class, and then trying to use an event present in the derived class.

If "Main" derives from UserControl, and you declare a "Main" object as "UserControl", only the base class methods, properties and events (the ones present in "UserControl") should be available. This is what is called a downcasting.

Comment: The problem was that Im not able to declare the class as "Main" since its inside the if-statement. Redeclaring "content" as "Main" might solve the issue but doesnt feel right.

Comment: I assume that you are declaring the object as UserControl outside of the if block, because depending on the if condition you will be using the Main class or another one also derived from UserControl, and later added to the masterpage.
So, how about not declaring the content object outside the if block, and instead declare inside with its right type, and adding the MasterPage.AddContent sentence to each "if" case?

Answer (score 0):

you can first define a base class and put the CloseClick event in it. and then your other usercontrols inherits this base class

```
class MyBaseUserControl : UserControl
{
    public static readonly RoutedEvent CloseEvent = EventManager.RegisterRoutedEvent(
    "CloseClick", RoutingStrategy.Bubble, typeof(RoutedEventHandler), typeof(Main));
    public event RoutedEventHandler CloseClick
    {
        add { AddHandler(CloseEvent, value); }
        remove { RemoveHandler(CloseEvent, value); }
    }
}

MyBaseUserControl content;
if (value == "main")
{
    content = new Main();
    content.CloseClick += new RoutedEventHandler(closeClick);
} else {
    ...
    ...
}
MasterPage.addContent(content);
```

Comment: This solution works, but I would end up with alot of classes with just a few event handlers in them.